# React separate instances call same method with separate values

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, arguments

I need to render two separate `input[type="range]` each one with a separate `output` value.

I have created a set of components which pass up and down their data in order to render in the correct way.
BUT I cannot split the rendering of the two components I need to declare which `state` is been affected, I want to store that in a variable and pass it through in different cases.

Here is a codepen of what I'm doing:
http://codepen.io/wanbinkimoon/pen/NpEpre?editors=0011

Here are the lines I think are wrong:

```
handleChange() {
   let v = props.t;
   this.setState({
     v: event.target.value
 });
```

Which is a function that refers to an instance of `<Range />` declared like this:

```
<Range 
    name = 'X Value'
    t = {'xvalue'}
    value = {this.state.xvalue}
    change = {this.handleChange}
/>
```

I tried to pass in some arguments but returns me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a unique property from parent component for example: name, and assing that name to `input` field, try to use the same name as the `state` variable name.

Like this:

```
<input
    type="range"
    min={min}
    max={max}
    step={step}
    name={this.props.name} //assigning name
    value={this.props.value} 
    onChange={(e)=>this.props.change(e)} 
/>
```

Pass the `event` object to parent component. Use this `event` to update the state value. Like this:

```
handleChange(e) {
    //let v = props.t;
    let obj = {};
    obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
    console.log(event.target.value);
};
```

**Reason why it is working**:

State is any `object`, it contains key value pair, since we used same name as the name of state variable, we can use that name to update state value. When we pass an object in `setState` it replaces the values of `state`  variable by values passed in that `object`. Its like:

`state values = {x: 1, y: 2};`

`obj[x] = 5;`

now when we do `setState` it will merge these two `objects` and new `state` values will be: `{x: 5, y: 2}`

Check the working code:

```js
class Range extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };
  render() {
    let min = 0;
    let max = 500;
    let step = 1;
    return (
      <form>
        <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
        <input
           type="range"
           min={min}
           max={max}
           step={step}
           name={this.props.name}
           value={this.props.value} 
           onChange={(e)=>this.props.change(e)} 
         /> 
         <output>
           {this.props.value}
         </output>
       </form>
    )
  };
};

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      xvalue: 100,
      yvalue: 300,
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  };
 
  handleChange(e) {
    let obj = {};
    obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };
 
  render() { 
     return (
        <div className="formwrap">
          <Range 
              name = 'xvalue'
              t = {'xvalue'}
              value = {this.state.xvalue}
              change = {this.handleChange}
          />
          <Range 
             name = 'yvalue'
             t = {'yvalue'}
             value = {this.state.yvalue}
             change = {this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>
     )
   };
};

class Rect extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };
  
  render() {
     return (
        <div> 
           Rect
        </div>
     )
  };
};

class Wrap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Form />
            <hr />
         <Rect />
      </div>
    )
  };
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Wrap />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
```

Comment: I don't get it, can you explain better?

Comment: will explain, but first run the code check this is what you wanted ??

Comment: output is rendering, whenever you changes the range value, the updated value is coming in properly, check again.

Comment: In my instance is not rendering properly. Check maybe I missed something: http://codepen.io/wanbinkimoon/pen/jBQXmR?editors=0011

Comment: check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvQwVz?editors=0011, issue was you need to assign name props to input field, as well as name should be same as the state variable name, because it helps you to update state value :)

Comment: Yep now it's working! Can you explain me what you did with the obj there?

Comment: check the updated answer, let me know if you need any other help :)